# Is it not possible to iframe nytimes.com?

Tags: iframe, reload

I tried this, and it just reloads to nytimes.com  Any ideas?

```
<div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width:80%; height:100%; background-color:white">
<iframe border=0 width=50% height=1000 src="http://nytimes.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

they are using a frame breakout javascript, since it is their site there is nothing you can do. one possibility is instead of embedding their site in a frame, use a server side method to download the wanted content and display it inline on your site.

Comment: probably not, but it is doable - i figure they would notice the repeated hits from his server and eventually block it but it is still an option.

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to add to what Christopher Kelly said - they obviously don't want you to put their content in a frame, so you should not do it.  You may want to refer to their [terms of use](http://www.nytco.com/terms_of_use.html) to see what sort use of **their** content they are okay with.

This is what would be relevant:

> Trademarks, Copyrights and Restrictions. This site is controlled and operated by The New York Times Company. All material on this site, including, but not limited to, images, illustrations, audio clips, and video clips, is protected by copyrights, trademarks, and other intellectual property rights that are owned and controlled by The New York Times Company, its related companies or by other parties that have licensed their material to The New York Times Company. Material on this Web site is solely for your personal, non-commercial use. Such material may not be copied, reproduced, republished, modified, uploaded, posted, transmitted, or distributed in any way, including by e-mail or other electronic means, without the express prior written consent of The New York Times Company. Use of the materials on any other Web site or networked computer environment, or use of the materials for any purpose other than personal, non-commercial use is a violation of The New York Times Company 's copyrights, trademarks and other proprietary rights, and is prohibited.